# how spark master splits input data to different nodes

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using spark with mongodb , I want to know how input rdd splitted across different worker nodes in the cluster, because my job is to club two records(one is request another is response) into one , based on the msg_id ,flag(flag indicates request or response) fields, msg_id is same in both records.while spark splitting input rdd ,each split for each node then how to handle the case if request record in one node and response record in another node.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Spark master does not split data. It just controls workers.

Secondly, rdd splits (while reading from external sources) are decided by InputSplits, implemented through input format. This part is fairly similar to map reduce. So in your case, rdd splits (or partitions, in spark terms) are decided by mongodb input format.

In your case, I believe what you are looking for is to co-locate all records for a msg id to one node. That can be achieved using a partitionByKey function.

Comment: can i have one example of partitionBYKey in java please

Comment: I am not a java person....Please go through the doc.....I can give you a python example :)

Answer (score 0):

RDDs will be build based on your transformation(Subjected to the scenario) and master has less room to play the role here.Refer this link [How does Spark paralellize slices to tasks/executors/workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677407/how-does-spark-paralellize-slices-to-tasks-executors-workers?rq=1) .
 In your case, you may need to implement **groupby()** or **groupbykey()**  (this one is not recommended) transformations to group your values based on the keys(msg_id).

For example

```
      val baseRDD = sc.parallelize(Array("1111,REQUEST,abcd","1111,RESPONSE,wxyz","2222,REQUEST,abcd","2222,RESPONSE,wxyz"))  
      //convert your base rdd to keypair RDD    
      val keyValRDD =baseRDD.map { line => (line.split(",")(0),line)}  

      //Group it by message_id
      val groupedRDD =  keyValRDD.groupBy(keyvalue => keyvalue._1)  

      groupedRDD.saveAsTextFile("c:\\result")
```

**Result :**

(1111,CompactBuffer((1111,1111,REQUEST,abcd), (1111,1111,RESPONSE,wxyz)))
(2222,CompactBuffer((2222,2222,REQUEST,abcd), (2222,2222,RESPONSE,wxyz)))

In the above case, possibility of having all the values for a key in same partition is high(subjected to data volume and available computing resource at run time)